# Pymongo.find() only return answer

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am working on a code which will fetch data from the database using pymongo. After that I'll show it in a GUI using Tkinter.

I am using

```
.find()
```

to find specific documents. However I don't want anything else then 'name' to show up. So I used {"name":1}, now it returns:

```
{u'name':u'**returned_name**'}
```

How do I remove the **u'name':** so it will only return **returned_name**?

Thanks in advance,

Max

P.s. I have searched a lot around the web but couldn't find anything which would give me some argument to help me.

Comment: Please, if you're not willing to do it for your entire question, at least format your code. It's impossible to read, let alone fix.

Comment: I'll try and make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see returned by `find()` call is a *cursor*. Just iterate over the cursor and get the value by the `name` key for every document found:

```
result = db.col.find({"some": "condition"}, {"name": 1})
print([document["name"] for document in result])
```

As a result, you'll get a *list of names*.

Or, if you want and expect a single document to be matched, use [`find_one()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one):

```
document = db.col.find_one({"some": "condition"}, {"name": 1})
print(document["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongo will return the data with keys, though you can as workaround use something like this

```
var result = []
db.Resellers_accounts.find({"name":1, "_id":0}).forEach(function(u) { result.push(u.name) })
```

This example is for NodeJS driver, similar can be done for Python

Edit (Python Code) -

```
res = db.Resellers_accounts.find({},{"name":1, "_id":0})
result = []
for each in res:
    result.append(res['name'])
```

Edit 2 - 
No pymongo doesn't support returning only values, everything is key-value paired in MongoDB.

Comment: this doesn't solve the question as asked because the key name is still returned from the database for each document. It's not clear from the question why that is a problem thoug.

Comment: it should not be a problem, op just want to save a step, to get all the values.